# Decay estimates for simple elliptic equations

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-functions

Let
and let $p(|z|)$ be the radial solution of the following equation
$$
\Delta p   + 4q = 0\quad \text{in } \mathbb{R}^n
$$
where

- $n\geq 2$,
- $0<\alpha<1$,
- $q \triangleq q(|z|) = \frac 1{1+ |z|^{2+\alpha}}$.

**Question**. Is it true that $p(|z|)\rightarrow 0$ as $|z|\rightarrow\infty$
and furthermore
$$
p(z) \sim  \frac 1{1+ |z|^{\alpha } }\quad \text{in }\, \mathbb{R}^n\; ?
$$

Answer (score 2):

The solution  decays like $r^{2-n}$ if $n \geq 3$. Setting $u=r^{\frac{1-n}{2}} v$, then
$$v''-\frac{(n-1)(n-3)}{4r^2} v +g(r)v=0$$ with $g=4q$. This gives the result if $n=3$ since $rg(r) \in L^1$ and then all solutions of the above equation behave like $1,r$ as $r \to \infty$ so that the decaying solution behaves like $r^{-1}$. If $n >3$ one obtains the result by using the Liouville transformation for the equation satified by $v$, as in Chapter 6 of the book by Olver, Asymptotics and special functions (with some care because the functions $\psi_{f,g}$ does not belong to $L^1$). I can write down the details if somebody is interested but I do not see a short way as above.

EDIT The case $n>3$ goes as follows. Let $f(r)=(n-1)(n-3)r^{-2}$ and $\phi(r)=\int_1^r \sqrt{f(s)}ds=\frac{\sqrt{(n-1)(n-3)}}{2}\log r$. The function $w(s)=f^{\frac 14}(\phi^{-1}(s)) v(\phi^{-1}(s))$ satisies the equation $$w''(s)=\left (1+\frac{\psi_{f,g}(\phi^{-1}(s))}{\sqrt{f(\phi^{-1}(s))}}\right )w(s)$$
with
$$\psi_{f,g}(r)=f^{-\frac 14}(-\frac {d^2}{dr^2} +g)f^{-\frac 14}$$ (see the book of Olver for this way). Performimg all computations one obtains
$$ w''(s)= \left ( \frac{(n-2)^2}{(n-1)(n-3)} +O(e^{-\gamma s}) \right )w(s)$$ for some $\gamma>0$ (since $g$ decays more than quadratically). Then the decaying solution $w$ behaves like $w(s) \approx e^{-\frac {n-2}{\sqrt{(n-1)(n-3}}s}=r^{1-\frac n2}$. Coming back first to $v$ and then to $u$ one gets $u \approx r^{2-n}$.

Comment: Thanks! I also write something about it.\begin{gather*}
 p''(r)+\frac{n-1}{r}p'(r)=-4q, \\  (r^{n-1}p')'=r^{n-1}p''+(n-1)r^{n-2}p'=r^{n-1}(-4q),\\\int_{0}^{\rho}(s^{n-1}p(s)')'\,\mathrm{d} s=\int_{0}^{\rho}s^{n-1}(-4q(s))\,\mathrm{d}s=\rho^{n-1}p'(\rho),\\\rho^{1-n}\int_{0}^{\rho}s^{n-1}(-4q(s))\,\mathrm{d}s=p'(\rho)\Rightarrow \int_r^{\infty}\rho^{1-n}\int_{0}^{\rho}s^{n-1}(-4q(s))\,\mathrm{d}s=\int_r^{\infty}p'(\rho)\,\mathrm{d}\rho
 \end{gather*}but loss the information about $p(z)$ in the infinity. I also quite interesting about your details! Thanks again!

Comment: I added (shortly) the case $n>3$ but I did not consider $n=2$.

Comment: Thanks! But it seems $\alpha$ has no effect on the infinity property of the solution $p(r)$?

Comment: Not at the first oder approximation but it should enter the remainder.